# Interpretation of a summation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

If I want to interpret the following summation:

$$\sum_{d|n} (n/d) \tau (d),$$

Where $\tau$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$, i.e. $$\tau (n) = \sum_{d|n} 1.$$

My opinion is:

The above summation, $$\sum_{d|n} (n/d) \tau (d),$$ can be interpreted as $$\sum_{d|n} (n/d)\sum_{d|n} 1 ,$$ but then what?

The given picture below contains another interpretation for the summation(if we let $n = p^k$):

[image]

But I do not know how my interpretation and the picture can be the same, may be if we consider the 2 summation signs in my interpretation as 1 sign because the index of the summation is the same , this will make my interpretation and the photo's interpretation close to each other, but still  in  the interpretation in the picture the numerator is 1, 2, 3, ....., k+1, which I do not understand why, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: your function is a number theoretic multiplicative function. It is determined by its values on primes and prime powers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function

Comment: yes I know that it is a multiplicative function , but how this can answer my question? @WillJagy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\tau (n) = \sum_{d|n} 1$ but $\tau (d) = \sum_{m|d} 1$ for $m \leq d$, the number of divisors of $\textbf{d}$. Hence

$$\sum_{d|n} (n/d) \tau (d) = \sum_{d|n} (n/d)\sum_{m|d} 1$$

And if you replace $n$ with $p^k$ for some prime $p$, $$
\sum_{d|n} (n/d) \tau (d) = \sum_{p^i|p^k} (p^k/p^i) \tau (p^i) = p^k\sum^k_{i=0} (1/p^i) \tau (p^i) \\
= p^k\sum^k_{i=0} (1/p^i) (i+1) = \sum^k_{i=0} p^{k-i} (i+1) = \sum^k_{i=0} p^{i} (k+1-i)\\
$$ Note that $\tau (p^i) = i+1$, and the last equality follows from a change of index.

Comment: why did you substitute for d by $p^{i}$, is this step important ? I mean what if we left d as it is without substituting for it?

Comment: For a prime $p$, if $d|p^k$, then $d$ must be in the form of $p^i$, where $0 \leq i \leq k$. I just wrote $p^i$ to make things a bit cleaner ;)

Comment: yes, really it is much clearer thanks :) for your very beautiful answer.

Comment: And how is the last equality came?

Comment: It comes from a change of index. Denote as $i'$ for the index we want in the last equation, then let $k-i=i'$ and we have $i+1=k-i'+1$. You can check to see that the boundaries are the same (i.e. k-0=k, k-k=0)